# Update existing item in custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have chat app which have two types of elements in listview

```
message
message
message
  Header
message
message
```

In my app after showing **Header** I need to remove or hide it after particular time or event. 
I know that I can get this item by position. The problem is that my listview dynamically can grow from both sides. 
What can I do in this situation.
You can see my custom adapter in this question: [In Android how to prevent updating existing items on notifyDataSetChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557875/in-android-how-to-prevent-updating-existing-items-on-notifydatasetchanged)

Answer (score 1):

I would extend a Class by another and give your ArrayAdapter the parent Class.

In your drawer you may work with

```
 if (position.get(pos) instanceOf MessageHeader) { } 
 else if (position.get(pos) instanceOf SimpleMessage) {}
```

your Class may look like that:

```
 class Message {
    private String text;  
 }
 class SimpleMessage extends Message {}
 class HeaderMessage extends Message {}
```

and your ArrayAdapter accept the Message

```
class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {}
```

If you want to add or remove items you can use the following way doing that:

```
 private ArrayList<Message> messages = null;
 public myAdapter(List myList) { this.messages = (ArrayList)myList; }

 public void addItem(Message message) { messages.add(message); forceUpdate(); }
 public void removeItem(int position) {messages.remove(position); forceUpdate(); }
 private voice forceUpdate() { notifyDataSetInvalidated(); notifyDataSetChanged(); }

 private List<Integer> getItemPositionsWithHeader() {
      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0, j = messages.size(); i <= j; i++) {
          if (messages.get(i) instanceOf HeaderMessage) {
             list.add(i); 
          }
      }
     return list;
 }

private void removeAllHeaderItemsFromList() {
      for (Integer i : getItemPositionsWithHeader) {
          messages.remove(i);
      } 
     forceUpdate();
}
```

Comment: My ArrayAdapter is working like you propose. My problem is how I can remove or hide element after showing it in listview, by calling for exampe adapter.notifydatasetchange;

Comment: the problem is that my listview can add elements from top and bottom, so item position will change. Is there a way to get Header item, without looping all list?

Comment: I solved my problem like this.
when I was assigning Headers, I will store this Header object in global variable(since I can have only one header for list). When I need to remove that Header, I just called adapter.remove(headerObject); and it will remove it.